# JSON Schema - multiple types

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have this schema. It checks comments, and works fine at the moment.

```
var schema = {
  id: '',
  type: 'object',
  additionalProperties: false,
  properties: {
    text: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 1,
      required: true
    },
    author: {
      type: 'number',
      required: true
    }
  }
};
```

My comment structure is:

```
{
  text: "Hello world!",
  author: 1
}
```

But now, I need to validate an array of objects like this. So I can get something like:

```
  [
    {
      text: "Hello world! Im comment #1",
      author: 1
    },
    {
      text: "Super awesome comment #2!",
      author: 0
    }
  ]
```

Sometimes I get one comment only so I get one object, and need to use first schema, but sometimes I get an array of comments, and my schema does not fit.

I heard about json schema **`anyOf`**, but I dont know how to do it.

Some like:

```
anyOf  
   schema-1 (object)
   schema-2 (array with objects)
```

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to have a common definition in one place, and then reference that common definition from two different options inside `oneOf`:

Here, we put the simple object definition inside `definitions`:

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "singleObject": {
            ... same definition as in your question ...
        }
    }
}
```

We then reference this schema, inside `oneOf`:

```
{
    "oneOf": [
        {"$ref": "#/definitions/singleObject"}, // plain object
        {
            "type": "array", // array of plain objects
            "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/singleObject"}
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "singleObject": {...}
    }
}
```

You can organise this a few different ways - I personally often end up with the simple-object definition as the root schema, and have the single/array switcher in `definitions`, so the schema for my documents is actually `http://example.com/schema#/definitions/arrayOrSingle`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. why not ```anyOf``` instead of ```oneOf```?

Comment: In this case, they'd be kinda equivalent, because it can't be both an object and an array.  However, in general, unless you explicitly want it to be possible to be both, using `oneOf` is equally easy to read and more explicit about expected behaviour.

Comment: You could argue that. But at the same time, `oneOf` is equivalent to XOR and `anyOf` is equivalent to OR. The most common usage of validating against *multiple types* as the title says, is imo to think of the types being chained with OR as you normally do. A lot of people don't even consider the existence of XOR in logic so I believe at least that should be pointed out in the text.